# displaying jtextfield data in jlablel on keyPressed event

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

i need to erase  data in jlabel via jtextfield whenever i pressed backspace or delete from current position.I figure out how to add data in jlable(numeric data) but don't know how to erase it or edit it.

//this is my code

```
            String  str = "";

       private void jTextField1KeyPressed (java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                       

           char ch=evt.getKeyChar();

            if(Character.isDigit(ch)
               str += ch; 

            jLabel2.setText(str);
        }



}
```

Comment: What's wrong with your code? What is happening or isn't that shouldn't or should (respectively)?

Comment: Use a `DocumentListener` instead of `KeyListener` and simply get the text from the field/document and replace the labels text

Answer (score 1):

- Use a `DocumentListener` instead of a `KeyListener`, it will be able to detect when the user pastes text into the field and/or is changed programmatically
- When the `Document` is updated, get the text from the field and set the labels text. There is little benefit in trying to update another `String` when the information is already available in the field/`Document`. If you "really" have to, use a `StringBuilder` instead, it's more efficient and is mutable

For example

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent;
import javax.swing.event.DocumentListener;
import javax.swing.text.BadLocationException;
import javax.swing.text.Document;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JLabel mirrorLabel;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

            JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
            field.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

                @Override
                public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    updateLabel(e.getDocument());
                }

                @Override
                public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    updateLabel(e.getDocument());
                }

                @Override
                public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                    updateLabel(e.getDocument());
                }

                protected void updateLabel(Document document) {
                    try {
                        mirrorLabel.setText(document.getText(0, document.getLength()));
                    } catch (BadLocationException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            add(field, gbc);

            mirrorLabel = new JLabel(" ");
            add(mirrorLabel, gbc);
        }

    }

}
```